# Google spreadsheet script sending emails twice

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

The problem is simple;  I want to send email via GAS, but each time the trigger runs, it sends the email twice.  I'd appreciate for any help.

```
function elpemail() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('list');
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var rowData = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

    var emailSubject = "(Something)";
    var emailBody = "(Something)"; 

    var recipientEmail = "example@example.com";
    var options = {
      htmlBody: emailBody
    };
 
    MailApp.sendEmail(recipientEmail, emailSubject, "", options);
    }
```

I googled this problem and found out bunch of people who had same problem with me.
The common answer was:

1. add lock on script.
2. do not use your function name 'onedit'.
3. make sure you have only 1 trigger.

The lock didn't work, and following is my trigger setting. It's the only trigger I have set.

[trigger setting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xj10I.png)

Comment: What is the trigger type? I can't find anything wrong in the contents of your question.  Check the issues and see if they are working on such an issue.  Multiple triggers have occurred in the past.

Comment: It is OnEdit only. I'm still struggling to find the problem.

Comment: Have you tried my solution below?

Comment: How do you want this function to work?  What is it that you edit on the sheet that you want to cause the function to send an email

Comment: The sheet is automated via Python code, putting datas into the sheet automatically. When I just put datas manually, the email is launched only once. However when the data is put via Python automation, all the emails are sent twice. I also tried to figure the problem out with Python code also; the only line it works with google sheet is 1) get the last row number  2) put new data as new row.

Comment: onEdit does not trigger on anything but user edits

Comment: Then it should be not onEdit but onChange. Sorry for the confusion. My native language is Korean and edit/change are quite similar with their meanings, so I was confused.

Comment: Please explain in detail how you edit your content and then how you expect the triggers to send the emails.  And if you are using e.changeType == "EDIT" then why is that not in your code?

Comment: To clarify, I've set onChange trigger, but when I used event object (e), it kept to generate error. (I know e should not be tested on script editor. Errors were also at actual operations.) As I failed to handle that, I excluded using e in this script.

Comment: The Python code will add new row of data each time it runs, via following lines:                 lastrow = len(worksheet.col_values(1)) + 1
                worksheet.insert_row(memodata, index=lastrow). 

As it comes into spreadsheet, the onChange trigger (not in function but in trigger setting) will shoot the function, and send the last row of the sheet as email.

Comment: Is the onChange trigger handler the same as the code posted in your question?

Comment: Yes, the script is same. It was just my translation confusion to say onChange as onEdit.

Comment: What changeType are you going to use?

Comment: The current script is not using e itself, but if I use it, the changeType will be INSERT_Row.

Comment: So this is your event object `{"authMode":"FULL","changeType":"INSERT_ROW","source":{},"triggerUid":"","user":{"email":"","nickname":""}}` but in your code you are triggering on any change type and on any sheet in the spreadsheet.  So you don't really know what's causing your triggers because your code has not been set up to eliminate all of the other change types.  If your code eliminated all of the other change types perhaps your problems could be solved.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Hearing your advice, I tried to set changeType, and then found out one of two operations stop before the changeType declaration. Still two operations occur, but as result only one operates to end, so I'm happy with it. I'll work more to improve this. Again, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: It is true that utilizing the changeType does not actually eliminate the other triggers but if in you  code you utilize changeTypes to control the flow of your code then you can have one changeType do one and another change type do another operation inside of the same code.  But if you have no conditional processing on changeType then you have no idea which changeType is causing the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry")
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'Sheet0' && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart == 1 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    //e.source.toast("Gate1");
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");//Reset the checkbox back to FALSE
    const [hs, ...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
    vs.forEach((r, i) => {
      var emailSubject = r[1]
      var emailBody = r[2];
      var recipientEmail = r[0];
      var options = { htmlBody: `<h1>${emailBody}</h1>` };
      if (r[3] != "SENT") {
        //e.source.toast(`Loop${i}`);
        MailApp.sendEmail(recipientEmail, emailSubject, "", options);
        sh.getRange(i + 2, 4).setValue("SENT");
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Here's what my sheet looks like:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Checkbox Here | Subject | Message | Sent |
| 2 | Redacted | Subject1 | Message1 | SENT |
| 3 | Redacted | Subject2 | Message2 | SENT |
| 4 | Redacted | Subject3 | Message3 | SENT |
| 5 | Redacted | Subject4 | Message4 | SENT |
| 6 | Redacted | Subject5 | Message5 | SENT |

You can edit whatever you want on the page and when you are ready to send then press the check box in A1 and it will send whatever does not have SENT in the sent column.  If you are still sending more than one then you have more than one trigger. No python automation required here.

You will need to create an installable onEdit trigger mine is name onMyEdit

This will work for an onChange trigger with changeType of EDIT.

```
function onMyChange(e) {
  const arg = e.source.getActiveRange();
  const argA1 = arg.getA1Notation();
  const sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  //e.source.toast(`Entry: ${e.changeType} ${sh.getName()}!${argA1}`);
  if (sh.getName() == 'Sheet0' && e.changeType == "EDIT" && argA1 == "A1" && arg.getValue() == true) {
    //e.source.toast("Gate1")
    arg.setValue("FALSE");
    const [hs, ...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues()
    vs.forEach((r, i) => {
      var emailSubject = r[1]
      var emailBody = r[2];
      var recipientEmail = r[0];
      var options = { htmlBody: `<h1>${emailBody}</h1>` };
      if (r[3] != "SENT") {
        //e.source.toast(`Loop${i}`);
        MailApp.sendEmail(recipientEmail, emailSubject, "", options);
        sh.getRange(i + 2, 4).setValue("SENT");
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Still works on checking the checkbox

Comment: I tried this, and the problem changed:
Before edit, all emails were sent twice. Now, all emails are still being sent twice, but some of them fails. 
I tried to put Logger.log and see how the whole script operates, but only info I could get was 'all of the script is running twice'.